# Phoenix error adding user to REST service

Tags: rest, elixir, phoenix-framework

I made this call:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "user": {
    "email": "leo.hetsch@testapp.com",
    "first_name": "Léo",
    "last_name": "Hetsch",
    "password": "notsosecure",
"username": "test1"
  }
}' "http://localhost:4000/api/users"
```

And on the server I get:

```
[info] POST /api/users
[debug] Processing by VirtualTeams.UserController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"user" => %{"email" => "leo.hetsch@testapp.com", "first_name" => "Léo", "last_name" => "Hetsch", "password" => "[FILTERED]", "username" => "test1"}}
  Pipelines: [:api]
```

This is in my user.ex file:

```
  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :password, :string
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :api_token, :string
    field :username, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :api_token, :username])
    |> validate_required([:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :api_token, :username])
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
  end

  def create(params) do
  changeset(%VirtualTeams.User{}, params)
  |> put_change(:password, hashed_password(params["password"]))
  |> put_change(:api_token, :base64.encode(:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(24)))
  |> VirtualTeams.Repo.insert()
end

defp hashed_password(password) do
  Comeonin.Pbkdf2.hashpwsalt(password)
end
```

Just to verify I did:

```
mix ecto.migrate

00:40:35.074 [info]  Already up
```

Why am I getting an error?

UPDATE:
Forgot the error:

```
{"error":"error creating user"}
```

In my controller I have this code, which has the error:

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    case User.create(user_params) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> render("user.json", user: user)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:bad_request)
        |> json(%{error: "error creating user"})
    end
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Can you add `IO.inspect(changeset)` in the error case? That should print the detailed error in your terminal.

Comment: At a superquick glance, you're requiring the `:api_token` field but not passing it in the params? It would be much easier to track the error if you use the `changeset` you get in `{:error, changeset}` returned by `User.create/1` :)

Comment: @whatyouhide - If you can put your comment as the answer I will accept it.  That was the problem. I removed :api_token from the validation section and it works.

Comment: @JamesBlack done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `:api_token` is required by `changeset/2`, but not present in the params from the request.

In general, it's useful to get a look at the `changeset` in `{:error, changeset}` (returned by `create/1` in this case) in order to see what validation failed.